# Question about calculating the top left and top right coordinates of a point on N*N matrix

Tags: discrete-mathematics

([Image uploaded here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnrkY.jpg)I'm trying to solve the classic n-queens problem using python.  The current solution that I have coded is `O(n^4)` and I wish to optimize it to `O(n^3)` by making some changes in the `check_diagonal()` function.

Given a tentative current position of a queen, say `(i,j)`, I wish to find out if any of the two diagonals passing through this point already have queens on them.  For this, given `(i,j)`, I wish to find out the starting co-ordinate of the left diagonal (ie,starting from top-left to bottom-right) and the starting co-ordinate of the right diagonal (starting from the top-right to bottom-left).

So, given a point `(i,j)`, how do I find the starting point of the left and right diagonals?  Thank you!

Note:  I did something like [this](https://repl.it/KtAJ/0) in Python, but it doesn't retrieve correct results for cases where the point is on one of the edges or on the main diagonal with `rows==cols`.

Answer (score 0):

The classic solution to this programming problem uses two auxiliary vectors that track occupancy of the diagonals. For one set of diagonals, $i+j$ is constant, for the other, it’s $i-j$. Offset these values by an appropriate constant amount so that you can use them as one-dimensional array indices. Checking that a diagonal is occupied before placing a queen becomes a simple array lookup.

You can do the same for the rows and columns, of course. Representing the board as these four vectors instead of the “obvious” two-dimensional array makes the entire occupancy check a matter of four array lookups.

However, to answer your specific question, I’m going to assume zero-based indexing. Since $i-j$ is constant for one of the diagonals, the corresponding element in row zero is $i-j$. If this is value is negative, that means that the diagonal hits the side of the board before reaching the first row. The square at which this happens can be found by symmetry, and it’s $(j-i,0)$. For the other diagonal, you would do a similar calculation with $i+j$, checking to see if this is $\ge N$, in which case you’ve hit the edge at $(i+j-(N-1), N-1)$.

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate and provide an example please?

Comment: I have included the image in the question.  You say, if `(i-j)` is negative, then its diagonal top can be found at `(j-i,0)`.  However, if you take `(2,4)` in the image, then its left-diagonal top is `(1,3)` which is not, `(j-i,0)`.

Comment: I did say **zero**-based indexing. Your is **one**-based, so you have to check for $i-j\lt1$ instead and find an appropriate entry that has a second coordinate of $1$ instead of $0$. The principle is the same. You’ll of course have to adjust the other diagonal as well since the max column number in your scheme is $N$ instead of $N-1$.